# Keep post format class with isotope filter

Tags: posts, loop, filters

When I add isotope filtering for displaying posts, I lose the format class.

WITHOUT isotope filtering:

```
<article id="post-22" class="post-22 post type-post status-publish format-image hentry category-burma">
```

WITH isotope filtering:

```
<article class="burma item isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 56px, 0px);">
```

I need to keep the format class (like "format-image" in the above example).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<ul id="filters">
<li><a href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
<?php 
    $terms = get_terms("category"); // get all categories, but you can use any taxonomy
    $count = count($terms); //How many are they?
    if ( $count > 0 ){  //If there are more than 0 terms
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  //for each term:
            echo "<li><a href='#' data-filter='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "</a>   
 </li>\n";
 //create a list item with the current term slug for sorting, and name for label
        }
    } 
?>
</ul>

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=50' ); 
//Check the WP_Query docs to see   how you can limit which posts to display ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<div id="isotope-list">
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
$termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "category", "format-name");  //Get the terms for this particular item
$termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms
    foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
        $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
    }
?> 
<article class="<?php echo $termsString; ?>item"> 
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                  the_post_thumbnail();
            } ?>
</article> <!-- end item -->
<?php endwhile;  ?>
</div> <!-- end isotope-list -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

and the JS:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

var $container = $('#isotope-list'); //The ID for the list with all the blog posts
$container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
    itemSelector : '.item', 
      layoutMode : 'masonry'
});

//Add the class selected to the item that is clicked, and remove from the others
var $optionSets = $('#filters'),
$optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

$optionLinks.click(function(){
var $this = $(this);
// don't proceed if already selected
if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
  return false;
}
var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
$optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
$this.addClass('selected');

//When an item is clicked, sort the items.
 var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
$container.isotope({ filter: selector });

return false;
});

});
```

Appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not describe what you edited to add the isotope filtering, but you seem to have removed `post_class()` from this line to add your isotope class:

```
<article class="<?php echo $termsString; ?>item">
```

change it to:

```
<article <?php post_class( $termstring . 'item' ); ?>">
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class

Comment: Thanks! This code did restore the class I needed but now the category is showing as category-burma instead of just burma which breaks the functionality of the filter.

Comment: BTW, I added the UL filters code to page-frontpage.php and the query code to content.php. Theme is Flat Theme by ShapeBootstrap.